# Posting to Twitter from any page after login/approval with PHP

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

Users on my website can login to Twitter and post their status on my website and twitter at once. I'm using https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth to connect to Twitter. Login and posting is performed on different pages of website.

This is login script:

```
public function loginTwitter() {
        $twitter = new TwitterOAuth(
                            $this->getContext()->params['social']['twitter']['consumerKey'],
                            $this->getContext()->params['social']['twitter']['consumerSecret']
            );
            $request_token = $twitter->getRequestToken($this->link('//User:connectFromTwitter'));

    // Saving to session (Nette Framework)
            $twitterSession = $this->getContext()->session->getSection('twSes');
            $twitterSession->oauth_request_token = $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
            $twitterSession->oauth_request_token_secret = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

            if ($twitter->http_code == 200) {
                $requestLink = $twitter->getAuthorizeURL($token);
                $this->redirectUrl($requestLink);
            } else {
                echo 'Error';
            }
}
```

This is callback script (**posting works right after user has been logged in**):

```
public function twitterOauth() {
    // $_GET parameter oauth_verifier
        $oauthVerifier = $this->getParam('oauth_verifier');

            // Session section
            $twitterSession = $this->getContext()->session->getSection('twSes');

            $twitter = new TwitterOAuth(
                            $this->getContext()->params['social']['twitter']['consumerKey'],
                            $this->getContext()->params['social']['twitter']['consumerSecret'],
                            $twitterSession->oauth_request_token,
                            $twitterSession->oauth_request_token_secret
            );

            $access_token = $twitter->getAccessToken($oauthVerifier);
            $twitterSession->access_token = $access_token;
            $user_info = $twitter->get('account/verify_credentials');

            // Saving to DB to be able to post without login
            $tm = new TwitterUserManager();
            if (!$tm->isInDatabase($this->getUser()->getId())) {
                $tu = new TwitterUser();
                $tu->setUser($this->loggedUser);
                $tu->setOauthProvider('twitter');
                $tu->setOauthUid("'".$user_info->id."'");
                $tu->setUsername("'".$user_info->screen_name."'");
                $tu->setOauthToken("'".$access_token['oauth_token']."'"); // Saving the access token for further posting
                $tu->setOauthSecret("'".$access_token['oauth_token_secret']."'");
                $tm->persist($tu);
            }

            $twitter->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'Hello ' . date('d.m.Y H:i:s'))); // <== HERE IT WORKS

            $this->redirect('User:socialConnect'); // Redirect to another page
}
```

This is posting function (User posts from any page):

```
    public function postToTwitter() {
        $twitterSession = $this->getContext()->session->getSection('twitter');

            $twitter = new TwitterOAuth(
                            $this->getContext()->params['social']['twitter']['consumerKey'],
                            $this->getContext()->params['social']['twitter']['consumerSecret'],
                            $twitterSession->access_token['oauth_token'],
                            $twitterSession->access_token['oauth_token_secret']
            );

            return $twitter->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'Hello' . date('d.m.Y H:i:s')));
}
```

When I use posting function I get this error:

```
stdClass(2) {
       request => "/1/statuses/update.json" (23)
       error => "Could not authenticate you." (27)
    }
```

Thanks for help in advance.

**EDIT: Solution:**

Use this to **connect** to Twitter (save all info into DB): 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html

Use this to **post** from any page: 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.service.twitter.html

Nice example: 
http://www.joeyrivera.com/2010/twitter-api-oauth-authentication-and-zend_oauth-tutorial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always used the Zend-Framework-Component: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.service.twitter.html

I think it's simple and I could confirm, that it works. You just have to read through the tutorial (see link above).

Comment: Is it possible to use the lastest ZF 2.0 or should I use 1.12?

Comment: Yep, correct! I didn't see your question. Zend Framework 1.12. I don't even know if this component is still available in ZF2. Also the link of documentation was for ZF1.12